# What comics feature Batman's alternate universe where Bruce Wayne dies?

Tags: story-identification, dc, batman

I read about the existence of another universe for Batman where Bruce Wayne dies. To avenge his death, his father turns into Batman, and his mom turns into the Joker.

Which comics feature these stories?

Answer (score 9):

[This version of Thomas Wayne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Wayne#Flashpoint) was invented for [the Flashpoint series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashpoint_(comics)), DC’s prelude to its “New 52” relaunch, in which an alternate universe is created when the Flash jiggles a whole lot (give or take; I’m not really a DC guy).

I *think* the Batman parts of the story are mainly featured in:

- *Flashpoint #1–5*
- *Flashpoint: Batman Knight of Vengeance #1–3*

(Although I’m pretty much just going by [Wikipedia’s *Flashpoint* article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashpoint_(comics)#Titles)).

Comment: _an alternate universe is created when the Flash jiggles a whole lot_. I hope that's exactly how they pitched the idea to the editors.

Comment: @Daft: me too. It wouldn’t be the craziest idea ever in comics.

Comment: It certainly wouldn't be the most unusual thing that has happened because of vibrating molecules...

Answer (score 2):

Flashpoint: where Bruce dies, inspiring Thomas Wayne to be a vigilante and his mother Martha loses her sanity and becomes the Joker

Earth3(new 52): Thomas Wayne Jr. (older brother) and Alfred kill whole family, he later becomes Owlman